# Django Forms - Many to Many relationships with quantity in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have three models: 'Product,' 'Vehicle,' and 'VehicleStock.' I'm attempting to create a form for adding a new 'Vehicle.' This form should allow the specification of the 'registry,' 'brand,' and 'stock' (which is a ManyToMany field). Additionally, I'd like to specify the quantity of products associated with the vehicle.

I've already tried using 'inlineformset_factory,' but it's not meeting my requirements. It creates a widget where you need to specify every product in the database. Instead, I want a widget that functions like 'add product,' enabling the addition of multiple product widgets for the same vehicle. How can I achieve this?"

**models.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    SKU = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    registry = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_kilometers = models.IntegerField()
    stock = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='VehicleStock')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.registry}'

class VehicleStock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

**forms.py**

```py
class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        exclude = ["total_kilometers"]

    registry = forms.CharField(
        label='Veic registry',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Registry'}),
        required=True,
        error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a Registry.'}
    )

    brand = forms.CharField(
        label='Veic Brand',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Brand'}),
        required=True,
        error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a brand.'}
    )
```

**base.html**

```html
  <form
          autocomplete="off"
          class="needs-validation createorder-form"
          id="createorder-form"
          novalidate
          method="post"
        >
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="orderid-input" />
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.registry.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Vehiculo Registry</label>
                {{ form.registry }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.registry.errors }}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.brand.id_for_label }}" class="form-label"> Vehiculo Brand</label>
                {{ form.brand }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.brand.errors }}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.stock.id_for_label }}" class="form-label mb-3 "> Vehiculo Brand</label>
                <br />
                {{ form.stock}}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.stock.errors }}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" id="addNewOrder-btn" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```